# How can I get all data exported by communication node for post processing in MA Tool of CI Studio?

Tags: sas

I am trying to do a post processing on data exported by the communication node. One option I have is to export the data in form of sasdataset and import it in the process node. But if I can get it directly from the macro varibale like &intable or anything similar, it would be easier for me. I have already tried &intable and &intable1. They only have subject_id level data and not all the data that is being exported by the communication node. Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: What SAS product are you using?  This does not sound like Base SAS, but some SAS solution.  "Communication Node" is not a standard SAS term -- at least none that I have encountered.

Comment: Marketing Automation tool which is part of Customer Intelligence Studio.

Comment: I recommend editing your title to reflect that.  Also consider asking SAS tech support.  I am not sure how many experts in that solution are answering questions here.

Comment: I had raised a SAS Tech support, but unfortunately it seems this doesnt fall under the purview of tech support. Also as suggested by you, I have changed the title.

Answer (score 0):

The communication node will be creating a sas dataset with the same structure as the export definition. The sas dataset can be used in the post processing node.

Comment: Yes. But how can I get the table name created by the communication node?

Answer (score 0):

Try an `inner join` to your exported dataset from `&intable`.

Something like:

```
Update exporteddata 
from tempdb.exporteddata 
inner join &intable
```

`&intable` is strictly subject IDs. Other attributes are not editable on that variable. Nor can you directly edit a field in the information map. But process nodes allow you to work with data that SAS has access to.

Worst case you can try setting the data to its own dataset and running a pass through query the database engine to perform the manipulation.